# Retrieve single from pairs

Tags: sql, duplicate-data

This is a SQL query question.

If you have a table like this:

```
ID1         ID2
1709    1689
1689    1709
1934    1501
1501    1934
```

And you want to retrieve like this:

```
ID1         ID2
1709    1689
1934    1501
```

How would you do that? Please note that (1709, 1689) and (1689, 1709) are similar pairs just the IDs being shifted. My purpose is to get a single tuple out of these similar tuples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, which should work in any dialect (you don't specify what product you're using) that supports CASE:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE WHEN ID1 < ID2 THEN ID1 ELSE ID2 END AS ID1,
    CASE WHEN ID1 < ID2 THEN ID2 ELSE ID1 END AS ID2
    FROM Table
```

This converts all the rows to have the lower ID first, then uses DISTINCT to remove duplicates.